# RunAs in Windows 7 vs XP

Tags: windows-7, uac

In windows XP, The "run as" box will give the option to run as different user and by default the username contain PCName/Administrator. in windows 7 the run as will just give you an empty box to fill with the username and password.
Is there anyway to invoke a default username for the runas box in windows 7?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a default profile you can use?

Comment: No, what i mean is that when you right client a program in XP and choose "run as" by default the the it show the other option of user is Computername\Administrator. In withdows 7, it's an empty pop-up box you need to fill. I'm asking if there is anyway i can invoke administrator as default username same as the XP.

Comment: you could create a `DOSKEY` alias for the command prompt `runas /profile /username program`.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down shift when you right click, more options will show up. The option you are looking for is `Run as different user`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Scott. 
I know how to do this, but i need somehow to auto fill the username box same as the XP.

Comment: Have you looked at the command line program [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true). Perhaps you can make a shortcut opening the program you want and pre-filling in the user you want to use. Its not the same gui but you just need to type the password for the account in the console window and it works exactly the same.